# Is there any non-web application of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, JavaScript is a general purpose language but mostly it is used for Web Applications.

I am curious to know whether anyone is using JavaScript for non-Web apps. Also, are there any tools available for non-Web application development?

Comment: This is a discussion question, no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a reasonable list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages): for example, it points out that Javascript can be (and is;-) used for the purpose of scripting such non-web apps as Photoshop and OpenOffice.org. On the same wikipedia page you'll find pointers to several stand-alone Javascript interpreters (i.e., ones that are not part of web browsers) and specs for making e.g. your Java non-web apps more easily scriptable by Javascript (via a [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine))-derived stand-alone interpreter).

Answer (score 3):

javascript can be used as a general purpose language, for instance you can write apps in [JScript.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a%28VS.71%29.aspx) on the .NET platform (though JScript isn't completely compatible with the javascript spec).

You can find some more uses outside of web applications here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Since the newer javascript engines (like [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) and [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/)) have been around there's been work on 'Server-Side JS' (which can also be used just as regular shell apps, of course).

My 2 favorites are [Narwhal](http://narwhaljs.org/) and [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org).

As far as 'tools' I'd go with the old stand-by's vim and bash :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create local desktop and mobile applications using JavaScript with a number of Web Runtime platforms. They include:

- [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) (Desktop & Mobile)
- [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/ajax/) (Desktop)
- [Palm webOS](http://developer.palm.com/) (Mobile)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (Mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have Javascript for example in [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) to customize PDF Files.

They are used in server-side projects too like Jaxer, a [Javascript Server](http://www.jaxer.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone did write a [Javascript OS](http://www.masswerk.at/jsuix/) (although it runs in the browser... but still, not your ordinary webapp).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has been in use for a while outside of web applications.  You can even obtain a parser for javascript and add it to your application if you want.  Then you an add custom functions to the javascript engine and allow your users to use a scripting language from within your application.

Answer (score 0):

Rhino is a JavaScript implementation written in Java that is not coupled to a browser:
http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

You could use it to build something server side.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB (from "humongous") is a scalable, high-performance, open source, schema-free, document-oriented database. You interact with it via JavaScript. Documents are JSON blobs.

Comment: Documents are actually _BSON_ and JavaScript is only used for the shell via the embedded spidermonkey VM. The actual database has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: The actual database code has nothing to do with JavaScript. The query/maintenance interface to the database is JavaScript. You interact with the BSON via JavaScript (as if it was JSON).
Arguing about code that's publicly available is weird.

Answer (score 0):

htlmwithjavascript.hta (HTML Applications) files can be run on Windows to do scripting with the convienence of HTML formatiing. The Windows scripting engine also supports jscript.

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard Widgets in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript in the Scripter MIDI effects plugin of Apple's Logic Pro X to create custom MIDI plugins.